# Turning this into an applet that can be run in a Web Page

Tags: java

```
package loan;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class loan extends JApplet {

    JLabel interestLabel = new JLabel("Interest Rate (e.g. 5.5 for 5.5%)");
    JLabel yearsLabel = new JLabel("Years");
    JLabel amountLabel = new JLabel("Loan Amount");
    JLabel monthlyLabel = new JLabel("Monthly Payment");
    JLabel totalLabel = new JLabel("Total Payment");
    JTextField jtfInterest = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField jtfYears = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField jtfAmount = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField jtfMonthly = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField jtfTotal = new JTextField(10);
    JButton jbtCompute = new JButton("Compute Payment");

    public loan() {

    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout());
    panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 2, 5, 5));
    panel1.add(interestLabel);
    panel1.add(jtfInterest);
    panel1.add(yearsLabel);
    panel1.add(jtfYears);
    panel1.add(amountLabel);
    panel1.add(jtfAmount);
    panel1.add(monthlyLabel);
    panel1.add(jtfMonthly);
    panel1.add(totalLabel);
    panel1.add(jtfTotal);

    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    panel2.add(jbtCompute, BorderLayout.EAST);

    add(panel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(panel2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    jbtCompute.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                compute();
            }
        });
    }

    private void compute(){
        double monthlyInterestRate = Double.parseDouble(jtfInterest.getText()) / 1200;
        double monthlyPayment = Double.parseDouble(jtfAmount.getText()) * monthlyInterestRate /
                (1 - (Math.pow(1 / (1 + monthlyInterestRate), Double.parseDouble(jtfYears.getText()) * 12)));
        double totalPayment = monthlyPayment * 12;

        jtfMonthly.setText("" + monthlyPayment);
        jtfTotal.setText("" + totalPayment);


    }

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        loan applet = new loan();
        frame.add(applet, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

I need to turn this into an applet that can be run on a web page.
I am having issues with the html file, but that is another story.
What would I need to do to modify this so it can be run on both a web page, and as an applet in a frame?

Comment: what exception does this throw? If String fields contains anything except other than numbers, then it should throw some exception.

Comment: I used toString() instead of getText().  Fixed that issue.  It was throwing some crazy error in the Double Class, then at the line I try to parse initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
jtfInterest.getText()
```

Comment: Thank you.  I figured it out, but now I have to convert this to be usable in a web browser.